# How to say "I am ok with NDA" formally

Tags: formality

NDA -> Non Disclosure Agreement
I am trying to write a formal sentence. Is it ok if i write "I agree to the terms and i will apply to the NDA"?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I am not asking for legal advice. This is language specific question. It is hilarious that i have to explain further. As i said i am looking for the correct **sentence.**

Comment: I think you mean "comply with", not "apply to".

Comment: If this is a formal contract, you should get a lawyer to write it.

Comment: This appears to be a request for legal advice, and legal advice is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: It’s an NDA. To “agree” with it, you’re supposed to sign it. You needn’t do more and can’t do less than that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELU cannot provide legal advice for formal consent to a contractual matter.

Comment: @jsw29 It is not a legal advice. It is a language specific question. You either don't understand the question or you are not in a position of giving advice. So long.

Comment: @Barmar That was what i was looking for. If you can write it as answer i will accept it as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I will apply to" is not correct in this case.

You will "abide by" the terms and conditions or you "agree to" the terms and conditions.

An NDA is a binding legal agreement so it it correct to say something like:

> "I have read, understood and agree to be bound by your Non-disclosure Agreement dated..."